# Как сделать плавно выезжающий блок?

Tags: css, html5, css3, css-animation

Хочу сделать точно такой же выезжающий блок (стиль не обязательно соблюдать) как 
[тут](https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level1/infocsharp.php). Слева 4 выезжающих блока

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вот накидал небольшой пример:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  left: -70px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  margin-top: 5px;
  transition: left .2s linear;
}

div:hover {
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

```css
.slide-container {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
}

.slide-container .slide {
  background-color: #232323;
  border: solid #777;
  border-width: 2px 2px 2px 0;
  color: #fff;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  margin: 16px 0 0 -170px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  -moz-transition: margin 1s;
  -o-transition: margin 1s;
  -webkit-transition: margin 1s;
  transition: margin 1s;
}

.slide-container .slide:hover {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.slide-container .slide .slide-content {
  float: left;
  width: 170px;
}

.slide-container .slide .slide-header {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.slide-container .slide:hover .slide-header {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-container">
  <div class="slide">
<div class="slide-content">Slide 1 contents</div>
<div class="slide-header">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
<div class="slide-content">Slide 2 contents</div>
<div class="slide-header">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
<div class="slide-content">Slide 3 contents</div>
<div class="slide-header">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

+Вариант с трансформацией:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;  
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-90%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-90%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-90%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-90%);
  transform: translateX(-90%);
}

li:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
  -o-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```